# Pyspark Autonumber over a partitioning column

Tags: pyspark, autonumber

I have a column in my data frame that is sensitive. I need to replace the sensitive value with a number, but have to do it so that the distinct counts of the column in question stays accurate. I was thinking of a sql function over a window partition. But couldn't find a way.

A sample dataframe is below.

```
    df = (sc.parallelize([
    {"sensitive_id":"1234"},
    {"sensitive_id":"1234"}, 
    {"sensitive_id":"1234"},
    {"sensitive_id":"2345"},
    {"sensitive_id":"2345"},
    {"sensitive_id":"6789"},
    {"sensitive_id":"6789"},
    {"sensitive_id":"6789"},
    {"sensitive_id":"6789"}
 ]).toDF()
.cache()
      )
```

[image]

I would like to create a dataframe like below.

What is a way to get this done.

[image]

Comment: just use `dense_rank`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are looking for [`dense_rank`](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.functions.dense_rank) function :

```
df.withColumn(
  "non_sensitive_id",
  F.dense_rank().over(Window.partitionBy().orderBy("sensitive_id"))
).show()

+------------+----------------+
|sensitive_id|non_sensitive_id|
+------------+----------------+
|        1234|               1|
|        1234|               1|
|        1234|               1|
|        2345|               2|
|        2345|               2|
|        6789|               3|
|        6789|               3|
|        6789|               3|
|        6789|               3|
+------------+----------------+
```

Answer (score 0):

This is another way of doing this, may not be very efficient because `join()` will involve a shuffle -

*Creating the DataFrame -*

```
from pyspark.sql.window import Window
from pyspark.sql.functions import col, row_number
df = sqlContext.createDataFrame([(1234,),(1234,),(1234,),(2345,),(2345,),(6789,),(6789,),(6789,),(6789,)],['sensitive_id'])
```

*Creating a DataFrame of distinct elements and labeling them `1,2,3...` and finally joining the two dataframes.*

```
df_distinct = df.select('sensitive_id').distinct().withColumn('non_sensitive_id', row_number().over(Window.orderBy('sensitive_id')))
df = df.join(df_distinct, ['sensitive_id'],how='left').orderBy('sensitive_id')
df.show()
+------------+----------------+
|sensitive_id|non_sensitive_id|
+------------+----------------+
|        1234|               1|
|        1234|               1|
|        1234|               1|
|        2345|               2|
|        2345|               2|
|        6789|               3|
|        6789|               3|
|        6789|               3|
|        6789|               3|
+------------+----------------+
```